# dealloc on Background Thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

Is it an error to call `dealloc` on a `UIViewController` from a background thread? It seems that `UITextView` (can?) eventually call `_WebTryThreadLock` which results in:

> bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool): Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread
>   other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling
>   to UIKit from a secondary thread.

Background: I have a subclassed `NSOperation` that takes a `selector` and a `target` object to notify.

```
-(id)initWithTarget:(id)target {
   if (self = [super init]) {
      _target = [target retain];
   }
   return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
   [_target release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

If the `UIViewController` has already been dismissed when the `NSOperation` gets around to running, then the call to `release` triggers it's `dealloc` on a background thread.

Comment: [My Solution (uses an NSTimer to force the last release onto the main thread)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353471/block-release-deallocating-ui-objects-on-a-background-thread/6482941#6482941 "My solution")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is an error to make a UIViewController releasing in a background thread (or queue). In UIKit, dealloc is not thread safe. This is explicitly described in Apple's [TN2109](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2109/) doc:

> When a secondary thread retains the target object, you have to ensure that the thread releases that reference before the main thread releases its last reference to the object. If you don't do this, the last reference to the object is released by the secondary thread, which means that the object's -dealloc method runs on that secondary thread. This is problematic if the object's -dealloc method does things that are not safe to do on a secondary thread, something that's common for UIKit objects like a view controller.

However, it's quite hard to respect this rule and if you put `precondition(Thread.isMainThread)` in all your view controller `dealloc`/`deinit()`, you probably would notice very weird (and hard to fix) cases in which this rule is not respected.

It seems that Apple is aware of this fragility and is moving away from this rule. In fact, when you annotate a class with @MainActor, everything is ensured to be executed in the Main Thread, except `deinit()`. In Swift 6, the compiler prevents you from calling main actor code from `deinit()`.

Even if in the past we have been asked to ensure deallocation in the main thread, in the future we will be asked to ensure that deallocation can happen in any thread.

Comment: 4 years later, and the correct answer appears! Nice job - the TN was published a few months after my question, so it seems I wasn't the only one confused by this behavior.

Answer (score 6):

The simple rule is that it's an error to do *anything* on a `UI*` from a background thread.

Comment: What about `performSelectorOnMainThread`? Is this documented anywhere? All I've seen is rather vague references to "don't manipulate UI in background thread" - which is a lot less restrictive than your *anything*.

Comment: It's the normal way to call performSelectorOnMainThread: if you want to manipulate the UI from a background thread.

Comment: @schaechtele - Are you calling [UIViewController performSelectorOnMainThread:], or [self performSelectorOnMainThread:] when you do a cross-thread call from a different object?

Comment: I think, that performSelectorOnMainThread: can be called on an object only, means, is no class-method. So you have to call it on self (or another object).

Answer (score 3):

The second post here had useful info, but their answer didn't work for me.

[UIWebView in multithread ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945082)

It also seems that this may have been addressed in iPhone OS 4, but not sure.

I ended up not releasing my UIWebView in the controller's dealloc when [NSThread isMainThread] was NO.  Would rather leak than crash (until I get a better solution).

Comment: Yep - same problem. I solved it by just doing the release on the main thread, but sutorekease would work as well, I suppose.
My main concern is whether it's expected behavior or not In ObjC. I should check iPhone 4 to see if it's changed - which would at least give some indication that it's a bug.

Comment: I think this is "fixed" in iOS4, at least based on cursory testing

Answer (score 2):

It is an error to call dealloc on anything at any time.  You should only ever call release.

You should not access any UI related instances from a background thread.  This includes using getter methods because they may modify things internally.  However, retain and release are thread safe for any object at any time, as long as the normal rules for retain and release are followed.  UI related instances include any object that is referenced by an active UIView or UIViewController.

performSelectorOnMainThread does not do anything more than retain an object until it gets to the main thread.  It is safe to call on any UI related object.

Comment: Right. I only call release, but since it's the last release it ends up calling dealloc internally. If release is thread agnostic, then it follows that dealloc must be as well - right? So, is _WebTryThreadLock just a (possibly buggy) exception to the rule?