# Do UIKit objects need to dealloc on the main thread?

Tags: uikit

With respect to `UIView`, Apple has some comments on threading recommendations:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW147

> Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the
>   main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the UIView
>   class from code running in the main thread of your application. The
>   only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view
>   object itself but all other manipulations should occur on the main
>   thread.

Is it generally (un)safe to dealloc a UIView object in a background thread?  I'm looking for some supporting documentation in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, UIKit objects need to dealloc on the main thread. It is not safe to dealloc a UIView object in a background thread. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746197/dealloc-on-background-thread/24410372#24410372) for more details.

Comment: There actually seems to be some hacky code inside UIView/UIViewController to ensure dealloc always gets called on the main thread, even if the last reference is released from a background thread. I wrote some test cases to verify this myself. See this discussion for reference: https://forums.swift.org/t/deinit-and-mainactor/50132/11

Answer (score 0):

iOS Developer Library docs link to **NSView Restrictions** section so I guess they apply also to UIView.

> **NSView Restrictions**
>
> The NSView class is generally not thread-safe. You should create, **destroy**, resize, move, and perform other operations on NSView objects only from the main thread of an application. Drawing from secondary threads is thread-safe as long as you bracket drawing calls with calls to lockFocusIfCanDraw and unlockFocus.

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH12-123427

I hope this helps.